# Symfony 2.8 LDAP authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to use LDAP Authentication with Symfony 2.8 but I'm not being able to Login.

I configured everything according to the docs ([ldap](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/ldap.html)), tried a lot of different things, but nothing managed to solve it.
I'm able to query my ldap server, the login form correctly shows "Invalid credentials" if I misspell my password, but if I enter the correct user and password nothing seems to happen. I'm always stuck into the login page without a session.

I've been debugging with xdebug symfony ldap classes and on the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Use\LdapuserProvider I found that my user is correctly returned from LDAP, Symfony creates a user with the returned information, but in the end I'm still not logged in and the LdapProvider doesn't create a session.

Has anyone managed to configure ldap with success?
Does anyone know if is needed to create a User Entity class or configure something not covered on docs?

Those are my current configs:

services.yml:

```
ldap:
    class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
    arguments:
        - "my ip"           # host
        - 389               # port
        - 3                 # version
        - false             # SSL
        - false             # TLS
```

security:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service:         ldap
            base_dn:         ou=MyOU,dc=myDomain,dc=lan
            search_dn:       "admin-user@myDomain.lan"
            search_password: MyPassword
            filter:          ({uid_key}={username})
            default_roles:   ROLE_USER
            uid_key:         sAMAccountName

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: my_ldap
        anonymous: ~

        form_login_ldap:
            provider:    my_ldap
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login
            service:     ldap
            dn_string:   "{username}@mydomain.lan"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED] }

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
```

Logs:

```
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\UserController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://noc/app_dev.php/login"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":169,"args":["/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1534,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3612,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3540,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2131,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php","line":40,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php","line":61,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php","line":184,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php","line":46,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":140,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":125,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] php.INFO: The "find" method is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the "query" method instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":63,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":63,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/LdapUserProvider.php","line":62,"function":"find","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\LdapClient","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/LdapBindAuthenticationProvider.php","line":65,"function":"loadUserByUsername","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\User\\LdapUserProvider","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php","line":70,"function":"retrieveUser","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\LdapBindAuthenticationProvider","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php","line":80,"function":"authenticate","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\UserAuthenticationProvider","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php","line":112,"function":"authenticate","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\AuthenticationProviderManager","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php","line":146,"function":"attemptAuthentication","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\AbstractAuthenticationListener","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php","line":184,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php","line":46,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":140,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":125,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"ddias"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://noc/app_dev.php/"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":169,"args":["/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1534,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3612,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3540,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2131,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2986,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2628,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1863,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1778,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":140,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":125,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.WARNING: Username could not be found in the selected user provider. {"username":"ddias","provider":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\User\\InMemoryUserProvider"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:70)"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\UserController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://noc/app_dev.php/login"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":169,"args":["/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1534,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3612,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3540,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2131,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2986,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2628,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1863,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1778,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":140,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":125,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:24] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-03-08 15:48:25] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"11e2b4","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://noc/app_dev.php/_wdt/11e2b4"} []
[2017-03-08 15:48:25] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":169,"args":["/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1534,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3612,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3540,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2044,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_AuthorizationCheckerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3134,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getTwigService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3389,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getWebProfiler_Controller_ProfilerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2553,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2170,"function":"createController","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\ControllerResolver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php","line":46,"function":"getController","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ControllerResolver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":132,"function":"getController","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\TraceableControllerResolver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
```

Comment: Could you post your full securty.yml file? What does your access control section look like? Are there any messages in the logs?

Comment: @ChadSikorra full security file and logs posted

Comment: Are you use you didn't forget a domain prefix in the dn_string ? Like dn_string: 'domain\{username}' ? Something like that. I'd recommand you to test first the ldap with pure php functions, step by step, so you can figure out what is wrong. I had the same issue and had to do a lot of try/error to have a working config.

Comment: @COil querying AD is not a problem, It's working properly and returning the user info. The problem is creating a session and stay logged

Comment: Does adding: `login: pattern: ^/login$ anonymous: ~` to your firewall (after the `main` section help (anonymous and pattern on a separate line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK look like I found the problem...

Removing in_memory provider solve it... if you notice at line 9 on my logs, my user was not found and then at line 10 the TokenStorage was Populated with an anonymous Token again.

So LDAP provider logged me in, and the in_memory provider logged me out.